# Angular/Guards/RxJS. Wait until parents Guard ends with data response and check data in Child Guard

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am wondering if it is possible to check in child component's guard a data which was called from parent's guard. I have created parent components with employees. I used a guard to make an action to call data from server. I would like to check it on child component's guard to check if param ID from url is correct with data. If employee.ID is not in Array of Employees it shoud redirect and handle and error,

App-routing.module.ts

```
{
    path: 'pracownik',
    component: components.EmployeeComponent,
    canActivate: [guards.EmployeesGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: components.CreatorComponent,
        canActivate: [ guards.EmployeeGuard],
        pathMatch: "full"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Parent Guard: EmployeesGuard

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.employeesStateService.loaded$.pipe(
      map(loaded => {
        if (!loaded) {
          this.employeesStateService.load();
        }
        return true;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
```

Child Guard: EmployeeGuard:

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.employeesStateService.employees$.pipe(
      map(employees => {
        if (employees.some(employee => employee.ID === next.params.id)){
          return true
        }
        return false
      }),
    )
  }
```

EmployeesStateService

```
export class EmployeesStateService {

  public employees$: Observable<Employee[]>
  public loading$: Observable<boolean>
  public loaded$: Observable<boolean>

  constructor(private store$: Store<EmployeesStateService>) {
    this.employees$ = store$.pipe(select(EmployeesSelectors.selectEmployees));
    this.loading$ = store$.pipe(select(EmployeesSelectors.selectEmployeesLoading))
    this.loaded$ = store$.pipe(select(EmployeesSelectors.selectEmployeesLoaded))
  }

  public load() {
    this.store$.dispatch(EmployeesActions.loadRequest());
  }

  public createEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    this.store$.dispatch(EmployeesActions.createEmployee({ employee }));
  }
}
```

I would like to wait untill employees come to the ngrx store, and check it to enable a route. I have tried with retry(), but it does not help me. Any sugestions?

Best regards.

Edit.I added EmployeesStateService.

Comment: Can you show your employeesStateService file?

Comment: I am assuming that your employees$ Observable simply does not trigger the thread and therefore the guard is just waiting for data

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found the solution. If we call to the store to take any data, then we should filter it in the child component. If the id is not equal to any employee we can throw error or redirect somewhere.

```
export class EmployeeGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private employeesStateService: EmployeesStateService) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.employeesStateService.employees$.pipe(
      filter(employees => employees.length > 0),
      map(employees => {
        console.log(employees);
        if (employees.some(employee => employee.ID === Number(next.params.id))){
          return true
        }
        return false
      }),
      take(1),
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a brilliant solution, working fine for me. Thank You 

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it looks like the problem is that the thread is not triggered, since there were no changes, for this to work, you can try something like this

```
  contructor(private store$: Store<EmployeesStateService>) {}
  
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.store$.pipe(
      select(EmployeesSelectors.selectEmployees),
      take(1),
      map(employees => employees.some(employee => employee.ID === next.params.id)),
    )
  }
```

Comment: It does not work in my case. employees.guard start the load action which call the http get data from localjson, effect catch it, and wait for response, after it it switchmap the action to successfull and return to the reducer to change the state of employees. I have checked console log on parent guard and it starts first. Child guard shoud wait for data from store if employees are not empty and then check the id. I hope it can help you about the process information :)